# How can I pass multiple columns to the table1::table1 function without listing them?

Tags: r

I am using the table1 function from the 'table1' R package to create a fundamental descriptive table of numbers and percentages for several variables within a data frame (no stratification). I have been using the following code:

```
new_table<- table1::table1(var1 + var2 + var3, dataset= data)
```

This works well and does what I need. However, I have over 300 variables and don't want to type them all into the first argument individually. How can I specify all variables of interest in a way that the table1 function will accept?

Answer (score 1):

Using formula notation you could use `~.` to get a table of summary stats for all columns of your dataframe. Note however, that doing so requires to pass your dataset to the `data` argument.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
new_table <- table1::table1(~., data = mtcars)

new_table
#>                                  Overall
#> 1                                 (N=32)
#> 2                  mpg                  
#> 3            Mean (SD)       20.1 (6.03)
#> 4    Median [Min, Max] 19.2 [10.4, 33.9]
#> 5                  cyl                  
#> 6            Mean (SD)       6.19 (1.79)
#> 7    Median [Min, Max] 6.00 [4.00, 8.00]
#> 8                 disp                  
#> 9            Mean (SD)         231 (124)
#> 10   Median [Min, Max]   196 [71.1, 472]
#> 11                  hp                  
#> 12           Mean (SD)        147 (68.6)
#> 13   Median [Min, Max]   123 [52.0, 335]
#> 14                drat                  
#> 15           Mean (SD)      3.60 (0.535)
#> 16   Median [Min, Max] 3.70 [2.76, 4.93]
#> 17                  wt                  
#> 18           Mean (SD)      3.22 (0.978)
#> 19   Median [Min, Max] 3.33 [1.51, 5.42]
#> 20                qsec                  
#> 21           Mean (SD)       17.8 (1.79)
#> 22   Median [Min, Max] 17.7 [14.5, 22.9]
#> 23                  vs                  
#> 24           Mean (SD)     0.438 (0.504)
#> 25   Median [Min, Max]       0 [0, 1.00]
#> 26                  am                  
#> 27           Mean (SD)     0.406 (0.499)
#> 28   Median [Min, Max]       0 [0, 1.00]
#> 29                gear                  
#> 30           Mean (SD)      3.69 (0.738)
#> 31   Median [Min, Max] 4.00 [3.00, 5.00]
#> 32                carb                  
#> 33           Mean (SD)       2.81 (1.62)
#> 34   Median [Min, Max] 2.00 [1.00, 8.00]
```

And in case you want to select only some columns then `reformulate` might be handy to create the formula, e.g. in the example below I exclude `"carb"` and `"am"` from the table:

```r
table1::table1(reformulate(setdiff(names(mtcars), c("carb", "am"))), data = mtcars)
#>                                  Overall
#> 1                                 (N=32)
#> 2                  mpg                  
#> 3            Mean (SD)       20.1 (6.03)
#> 4    Median [Min, Max] 19.2 [10.4, 33.9]
#> 5                  cyl                  
#> 6            Mean (SD)       6.19 (1.79)
#> 7    Median [Min, Max] 6.00 [4.00, 8.00]
#> 8                 disp                  
#> 9            Mean (SD)         231 (124)
#> 10   Median [Min, Max]   196 [71.1, 472]
#> 11                  hp                  
#> 12           Mean (SD)        147 (68.6)
#> 13   Median [Min, Max]   123 [52.0, 335]
#> 14                drat                  
#> 15           Mean (SD)      3.60 (0.535)
#> 16   Median [Min, Max] 3.70 [2.76, 4.93]
#> 17                  wt                  
#> 18           Mean (SD)      3.22 (0.978)
#> 19   Median [Min, Max] 3.33 [1.51, 5.42]
#> 20                qsec                  
#> 21           Mean (SD)       17.8 (1.79)
#> 22   Median [Min, Max] 17.7 [14.5, 22.9]
#> 23                  vs                  
#> 24           Mean (SD)     0.438 (0.504)
#> 25   Median [Min, Max]       0 [0, 1.00]
#> 26                gear                  
#> 27           Mean (SD)      3.69 (0.738)
#> 28   Median [Min, Max] 4.00 [3.00, 5.00]
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan, that has worked perfectly! I assume the '.' specifies all columns in the dataframe?

Comment: Yep. `.` will select all columns in your data.frame.

Comment: And just as a reference. In case you don't want to select all columns then `reformulate` might be useful, e.g. using `table1::table1(reformulate(setdiff(names(mtcars), "carb")), data = mtcars)` will give a table for all columns except `"carb"`.

Comment: @BenBolker. Thx Ben. Added it to my answer.